# ECharts - Getting a single splitLine to render in a stacked bar chart

Tags: echarts

Trying to get a single split line to render on a stacked bar graph.

Here's the code:

```
options = {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Graph 1', 'Graph 2']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '7%',
        right: '5%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'category',
            data: [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
            axisLabel: {
                interval: 1
            },
            splitLine: {
                show: true,
                interval: function (param) {
                    //return param === 1;            //what I'm trying to get it to do
                    return param > 0 && param < 2;   //this doesn't work
                    //return param > 0;              //this works, but adds a split line to everything above 1 as well, not what I want. vice versa (param < 2) also works, but again not what I want
                },
                lineStyle: {
                    type: 'dashed',
                    width: 2,
                    color: '#767676'
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value',
            name: 'Y',
            nameLocation: 'middle',
            nameTextStyle: {
                padding: [0, 0, 8, 0],
                color: '#767676',
                fontSize: 14
            },
            axisTick: {
                show: false
            },
            axisLabel: {
                show: false
            },
            splitLine: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Graph 1',
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: 20,
            stack: 'Graph',
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#db0011'
            },
            data: [8000, 10000, 12000, 16000, 20000]
        },
        {
            name: 'Graph 2',
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: 20,
            barGap: '-100%',
            stack: 'Graph',
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#00a69d'
            },
            data: [4000, 5000, 6000, 8000, 10000]
        }
    ]
};
```

As per the above code,

- param > 0 works but will add a split line to everything beyond 1 (1 and 2)
- likewise, param < 2 will add a split line to everything before 2 (0 and 1)
- param > 0 and param < 2 doesn't work (no split line appears)
- setting a fixed number causes a split line to appear at the end of the graph as well, despite not being in the right interval (e.g. if my items went from 40 - 80 and I set an interval of 7, then the split line would appear before 47, 54, 61, 68, 75 and on 40 and 80)

How do I get a single split line to appear?

I've also seen [Echarts how do you add dashed vertical line in between specific bars on bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396553/echarts-how-do-you-add-dashed-vertical-line-in-between-specific-bars-on-bar-char), however I don't have enough knowledge on how to modify this to work with a stacked bar chart.

How I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up resolving this is:

```
var option = {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Graph 1', 'Graph 2']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '7%',
        right: '5%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'category',
            data: [40, '', 41, '', 42, '', 43, '', 44],
            axisLabel: {
                interval: 1
            },
            splitLine: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value',
            name: 'Y',
            nameLocation: 'middle',
            nameTextStyle: {
                padding: [0, 0, 8, 0],
                color: '#767676',
                fontSize: 14
            },
            axisTick: {
                show: false
            },
            axisLabel: {
                show: false
            },
            splitLine: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Graph 1',
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: 20,
            stack: 'Graph',
            data: [8000, 0, 10000, 0, 12000, 0, 16000, 0, 20000],
            markLine: {
                silent: true,
                symbol: 'none',
                label: {
                    show: false
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        name: "Test",
                        xAxis: 2.5,
                        lineStyle: {
                            color: '#767676',
                            width: 2,
                            type: 'dashed'
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Graph 2',
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: 20,
            barGap: '-100%',
            stack: 'Graph',
            data: [4000, 0, 5000, 0, 6000, 0, 8000, 0, 10000]
        }
    ]
};
```

A few things to note:

1. Add a bunch of empty string entries for your labels (x-axis). As can be seen above, data is [40, '', 41, '', 42, '', 43, '', 44] instead of [40, 41, 42, 43, 44].
2. Add zeroes in your graph series relative to where you inserted empty string labels in your x-axis data above (e.g. 4000, 0, 5000, 0, 6000, 0, 8000, 0, 10000). Do this for each graph you have.
3. In any of the graphs, insert the above markLine syntax I added to Graph 1. You will need to adjust the value of xAxis until you get the middle point.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k9hgj5zb/1/

Credits to this link: [Draw horizontal target line using EChart.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778542/draw-horizontal-target-line-using-echart-js)